# ssh key setup issue with id_rsa*

Tags: git, ssh, github

I am trying to set up my ssh key and I get this error.

```
$ rm id_rsa*

rm: id_rsa*: No such file or directory


$ cp id_rsa* key_backup

cp: id_rsa*: No such file or directory
```

Is this a major problem, or can I skip ahead?

Comment: This means that the key still does not exist. Just go ahead and use `ssh-keygen`

Comment: alright. That brings up "Enter file in which to say the key." What should I enter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the .ssh directory? Try sudo ls ~/.ssh to see if you have the keys in there

Comment: i ran sudo ls ~/.ssh and it came up with key_backup known_hosts

Comment: Ok you dont have any keys; you can genetate a pair. They wd b in .ssh if ypu did have them